# Query cannot parse variable defined datetime

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I'm having problems with writing a simple KQL query in Log Analytics Workspace. Basically I want to filter out all Application Registrations that have secret expiry date longer than 3 years.

I have made a following query, but I think my custom made datetime is still considered a string, instead of datetime type.
Here is the query:

```
//create a new date which is 3 years later than today
let newyear = format_datetime(datetime_add('year',3,datetime(now)), 'M/d/y, h:m:s.fff tt');
//Query the AppRegs for SecretEndDate ending at least in 2025
AppRegExp_CL
|project AppRegName_s, AppID_g, SecretEndDate_t
|where SecretEndDate_t >= datetime(newyear)
```

I'm always getting the same error:

```
Query could not be parsed at 'datetime(newyear)'on line [6,0]
```

I've tried using `makedatetime(), to_datetime()` but the result was the same.
Normally I'm not working on KQL queries, so maybe I'm missing something very obvious. I hope that you can help me out. 
 Thanks

Comment: One hideous issue: `h` is for 12 hours AM/PM notation, `H` is for 24 hours. I would read through https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/format-datetimefunction

Comment: Try just newyear in place of datetime(newyear) because newyear is a scalar value.

Comment: It makes no sense to convert `datetime` to string, definitely not to `M/d/y` format. 
Please share the type of `SecretEndDate_t`. If it is a `string` (and not `datetime`), please share a data sample.

Comment: Hi @RithwikBojja, I've used `newyear` before and I got the error `Cannot compare values of types datetime and string. Try adding explicit casts`. Hi @Joop Eggen, I know that's hideous but that's how the data is formatted when I see it in LAW and I wanted to adapt as best I could. @david-דודו-markovitz SecretEndDate_t is a datetime. It is presented in this format (I've copy pasted one entry) `3/18/2022, 3:16:33.011 PM` . Thanks all for answering

Answer (score 0):

Since `SecretEndDate_t` is of `datetime` type, no conversion is needed.

```
//create a new date which is 3 years later than today
let newyear = datetime_add('year', 3, now());
//Query the AppRegs for SecretEndDate ending at least in 2025
AppRegExp_CL
|project AppRegName_s, AppID_g, SecretEndDate_t
|where SecretEndDate_t >= newyear
```